# Correct way to include include scripts

Tags: url, include

I am including head.html and scripts.html in my template. Most of the scripts load except for 2 yet the path is the same for all of them. I {% include %} them.

If I change foundation.min.js to foundation.js it works. The min file exists.

**Update:**
This is because JS files are checked for errors before being loaded. For example, if I visit those URL's directly it will show me an error. Any way to stop that?

http://craft.dev/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js

[image: JS Error]

Update:

```
<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/velocity/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/velocity/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/wookmark-jquery/jquery.wookmark.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show me the part of your script.html file where you call the JS files?

Comment: Sure, updated it. It wasn't the HTML though, something parses those scripts and checks them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to include JS (or CSS) files, is to use the [includeJsFile](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includejsfile) tag.
This tag will queue your file and append to the end of the `<body>`.
If, for some reason, you don't want this (say you want to include JQuery in the `<head>`), I would just use `<script src="">` etc.

This might also solve your second problem.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work either. I don't know what is going on, but it might be a bug of sorts. It just fails to load the script if it has .min.js as the extension, and modernizr.js

Comment: Something to do with twig or craft checking the js file... !

Comment: Have you tried loading it directly with a <script> tag? Twig does nothing with script tags, so if that doesn't work, you can rule out a template problem.

Comment: Did you put your JS and CSS files in the templates folder? Then don't. If they're in your public folder, Twig or Craft has nothing to do with 'em.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I'll move them there. So it's all css images, js files, vendor stuff. CSS as well?

Comment: I keep everything in public, so Twig or Craft have nothing to do with it.